# H2H matches in soccer R programming

Tags: r

Is there any chance of not having to write the name of the soccer teams to see the H2H?.

I have these original variables:

```
Country    League    Season     Month monthDay  weekDay  Time  HomeTeam  AwayTeam  
Denmark    Superliga 2012/2013  July        13  Friday   17:30 Aarhus    Aalborg
```

and created new variables doing:

```
datafootball <-datafootball[, H2H := as.factor(paste0(HomeTeam,"-", AwayTeam)) ]  
datafootball <-datafootball[, H2Hinverse := as.factor(paste0(AwayTeam,"-", HomeTeam)) ].
```

New variables:

```
H2H            H2Hinverse
Aarhus-Aalborg Aalborg-Aarhus
```

If I want to check the H2H between teams(all rows) I can do it by writing the names of the teams involved:

```
 datafootball[datafootball$H2H == "Aalborg-Aarhus" | datafootball$H2H == "Aarhus-Aalborg" , ]
```

Then, I ask again:

Is there any chance of not having to write the name of the soccer teams to see the H2H?. Maybe a function. Maybe using HomeTeam and AwayTeam instead H2H and H2Hinverse.

Criteria:

Based on the upcoming matches that will be played. That is, if we assume that the next game will be Barcelona Real Madrid:

```
HomeTeam   AwayTeam  
Barcelona  Real Madrid
```

I want to show the H2H both playing at home and playing as a visitor. But being a lot of games every week and several leagues, I would not like to have to write the name of the teams and go one by one.

I'm sorry for asking but I'm not an expert programmer and I can not think of anything.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Based on what criteria do you want to select H2H? YOu need to provide a teamname somewhere, i guess? Or do you watn to see all H2H ?

Comment: Based on the upcoming matches that will be played. That is, if we assume that the next game will be Barcelona Real Madrid, I have HomeTeam Barcelona and AwayTeam RealMadrid. And I want to show the H2H both playing at home and playing as a visitor. But being a lot of games every week and several leagues, I would not like to have to write the name of the teams and go one by one.

Comment: If there are a limited number of teams, i.e if you're doing just one division, you could assign each team an ID in a separate table.

Comment: @ChrisLittler No, it's a database with several seasons of different leagues.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the H2H and H2H_inverse (I think)...
I added some lines you your data, for testing purposes..

```
library(data.table)

datafootball  <- read.table(text="Country    League    Season     Month monthDay  weekDay  Time  HomeTeam  AwayTeam  
Denmark    Superliga 2012/2013  July        13  Friday   17:30 Aarhus    Aalborg
                            Denmark    Superliga 2012/2013  July        13  Friday   17:30 Aarhus    Barcelona
                            Denmark    Superliga 2012/2013  July        13  Friday   17:30 Aalborg    Aarhus", header = TRUE) %>% setDT

datafootball
#    Country    League    Season Month monthDay weekDay  Time HomeTeam  AwayTeam
# 1: Denmark Superliga 2012/2013  July       13  Friday 17:30   Aarhus   Aalborg
# 2: Denmark Superliga 2012/2013  July       13  Friday 17:30   Aarhus Barcelona
# 3: Denmark Superliga 2012/2013  July       13  Friday 17:30  Aalborg    Aarhus

#give name of teams you want to see the H2H-matches of
teams <- c("Aalborg", "Aarhus")

#return all matches where both teams are playing
datafootball[HomeTeam %in% teams & AwayTeam %in% teams,]

#    Country    League    Season Month monthDay weekDay  Time HomeTeam AwayTeam
# 1: Denmark Superliga 2012/2013  July       13  Friday 17:30   Aarhus  Aalborg
# 2: Denmark Superliga 2012/2013  July       13  Friday 17:30  Aalborg   Aarhus
```

Comment: The problem is still the same. I have to write the name of all the teams. And in this case, I would have to create numerous vectors. One for every two teams. Anyway, you have given me an idea and I will create a vector with H2H  of all the next matches. For example:

H2Hmatches <- c("Aarhus-Aalborg", "Barcelona-Real Madrid")

datafootball[H2H %in% H2Hmatches & H2Hinverse %in% H2Hmatches,]

Thank you very much.